# How to make flutter Flipkart like search view in homepage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How to make `Flutter` Flipkart-like search view in homepage?

Is there any `Widget` available for that?

What I look for is an input box with right-side `Icon` and search suggestion listing which has items that can be selected.

Is there any widget available like this search bar in `Flutter` ?
[image]

Comment: You can try the [SearchDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) widget.

Comment: please show me some demo code

Comment: SearchDelegate is not a widget

Comment: Well, if you have a lot of time, you can probably watch [this awesome show](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI).

Comment: no , i don't have lot of time

Comment: It's not very simple to implement what you are trying to do, but this might help.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/search_demo.dart

Comment: @Midhilaj made an edit pls checkout.

Comment: Yes it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the **TextField**. Have look at following code:

```
Widget searchField() {
    return TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "search",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: (){
              print("cancel");
            },
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            width: 300.0,
            child: searchField(),
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.square(50.0),
        ),
        title: Text("example"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Switch(
            value: widget.stateofSwitch,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                darkThemeEnabled = value;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: 
      ),

    );
  }
```

This would result into [image: this]